# Using draggable() jQuery function in asp.net mvc4 project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use this `draggable()` jQuery function im asp.net mvc4 project. 
What jQuery libraries do I have to download in my project to use this function?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the jquery UI library.
You can find the API info at http://jqueryui.com/draggable/